# Where to find this broken link in order to remove it

Tags: theme-development

I have many broken links of this type -

http://isngs.com/wp-content/plugins/merobuilder/so-widgets-bundle/widgets/so-services-widget/css/fonts/service-background.eot?-7p8gp3

Please tell me how can i find this link and remove it.

Thanks,
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

Service-backgrout font is missing, as it looks. You have to find that font family and upload to  .../css/fonts directory.

Comment: How I am going to find that. Please let me know as I am new to WordPress.

Comment: Usually the file that ask for a font link of that type is a css file so you will have to check the css files located under so-services-widget and remove or comment out line that contain @import and the path of service-background.eot?-7p8gp3

Comment: Or if is not with `@import` it should be `@font-face { font-family: font-name; scr: url('path/to/service-background.eot?-7p8gp3') }`